# Zeppelin build failure - Failed to run task: 'grunt --no-color' failed

Tags: java, macos, maven, gruntjs, apache-zeppelin

I want to install Apache Zeppelin on OSX 10.8, but build fails for some mysterious reasons. Specs: Java 1.7, Maven 3.3, node v0.12.4 and grunt v0.1.13.

I'm running the following command:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

And I am getting the following output :

```
    [INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [ 18.310 s]
    [INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 07:53 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-14T18:32:13-05:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 78M/387M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:grunt (grunt build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'grunt --no-color' failed. (error code 3) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

It seems to be some errors with grunt, but I'm not sure.

Comment: We had similar problems and it was solved by cleaning the artifacts in local maven repository. It may work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs before BUILD FAILURE, you might have a javascript error.